# Unit testing a POST HTTP Request - how to expect the object that gets sent with request to be part of the api URL

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to create a simple unit test for a service. The service makes an HTTP POST call and sends a small object along to the server. I just want to test to ensure the API Url, `apiUrl` is being correctly called for the POST. However, Jasmine expects the URL by itself where it actually sends the URL + the data. But I have no idea how to take the data into consideration for the expect.

From Jasmine:

```
Expected spy HttpClient.post to have been called with 
[ 'https://localhost:56431/v2/Templates/function () { return fn.apply(this, arguments); }/Folder/321/Preview' ] 

but actual calls were 

[ 'https://localhost:56431/v2/Templates/function () { return fn.apply(this, arguments); }/Folder/321/Preview', Object({ groupId: '-', inviteMessage: '-' }) ].
```

I guess I could append the object directly to the apiUrl `toHaveBeenCalledWith` but is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

My service class:

```
export class TemplateService {
    apiUrl: string;

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private defaultService: defaultService) {}

    getTemplate(folderId: string, groupId = '', message = ''): Observable<Template> {
        let info = {
            'groupId': groupId,
            'inviteMessage': message
        };
        this.apiUrl = `${environment.base}/v2/Templates/${this.defaultService.currentAccountNumber}/Location/${folderId}/Preview`;
        return this.httpClient.post<Template>(this.apiUrl, info);
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
describe('TemplateService', () => {

    let httpClient: HttpClient;
    let service: EmailService;
    let defaultService: defaultService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        httpClient = jasmine.createSpyObj(
            'HttpClient',
            {
                post: observableFrom([
                    [
                        { body: '<h1>test</h1>', subject: 'Documents' }
                    ]
                ])
            });

        siteDefaultsService = jasmine.createSpyObj('defaultService', { currentAccountNumber: '123' });
        service = new TemplateService(httpClient, siteDefaultsService);
    });

    describe('post', () => {

        it('should make request to api url', done => {
            service.getTemplate('321', '-', '-').subscribe(results => {
                expect(httpClient.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(service.apiUrl);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try use `jasmine.any` or `jasmine.objectContaining`:

```
expect(httpClient.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(service.apiUrl, jasmine.any(Object));
```

or

```
expect(httpClient.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(service.apiUrl, jasmine.objectContaining({ groupId: '-', inviteMessage: '-' }));
```

Comment: Seems my comment I submitted yesterday didn't actually send. This is exactly what I was looking for--thank you so much!

Comment: @Timbo773 no problem :)